# Should i use correct mime for image redirect instead of text/html?

Tags: http, nginx, http-headers, content-type, mime

I got a lot image 301 redirect, some large image failed to load in safari, chrome network shows I use text/html for image 301 redirect, so, should I use correct mime to response image 301 redirect ? Any standards talk about the mime for redirect ?

Comment: What's the response body on the 301 response? Really an image?

Comment: @JulianReschke Nginx generate html for 301, so I should use text/html ?

Comment: The media type for the payload of a redirect should match what's in the payload.